# Robust ANOVA using the WRS2 Package: One way repeated measures of ANOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, robust

I'm unable to use the `rmanova` function in the WRS 2 package that computes a one-way repeated measures ANOVA (see [page 25](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WRS2/WRS2.pdf)).

```r
> head(WineTasting)
  Taste   Wine Taster
1  5.40 Wine A      1
2  5.50 Wine B      1
3  5.55 Wine C      1
4  5.85 Wine A      2
5  5.70 Wine B      2
6  5.75 Wine C      2

rmanova(WineTasting$Taste, WineTasting$Wine, WineTasting$Taster)

# Output
Call:
rmanova(y = WineTasting$Taste, groups = WineTasting$Wine, blocks = WineTasting$Taster)

Test statistic: F = 3.2614 
Degrees of freedom 1: 1.61 
Degrees of freedom 2: 20.92 
p-value: 0.06761
```

However, my dataset has one between factor (condition) and one within factor variable (time).

```r
df <- data.frame(subject = rep(1:30, 4))

# Create time variable with two levels
df$time <- rep(c("Pretest", "Posttest"), each = 60)

# Create condition variable with two levels
df$condition <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 30, times = 2)

# Simulate total score variable
set.seed(123)
df$totalScore <- round(rnorm(n = 120, mean = 50, sd = 10), 1)

# View first few rows of the data frame
head(df)

  subject    time condition totalScore
1       1 Pretest         A       44.4
2       2 Pretest         A       47.7
3       3 Pretest         A       65.6
4       4 Pretest         A       50.7
5       5 Pretest         A       51.3
6       6 Pretest         A       67.2

# Output
Call:
rmanova(y = df$totalScore, groups = df$condition, blocks = df$time)

Test statistic: F = 17.7285 
Degrees of freedom 1: -2 
Degrees of freedom 2: -2 
p-value: NaN 

Warning messages:
1: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for df$condition=A: first taken
2: In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  multiple rows match for df$condition=B: first taken
3: In pf(test, df1, df2) : NaNs produced
```

How do I get this working? I don't see a specific function for within and between subjects factor.